# Error al liberar imagen

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo una imagen en una ruta temporal, esta imagen la cargo y manipulo para mostrarla dentro de un picturebox, despues de cargar el picturebox deseo borrar la imagen pero me arroja un error indicando que la imagen esta ocupada por otro proceso.

```
    public void cargarImagenes(bool nuevo)
        {
            string pathTemp = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) +
@"\" + Application.ProductName;
            if (nuevo)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(pathTemp))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathTemp);
                }
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pathTemp);
                foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(rutaImg);
                tmpFile = Path.Combine(pathTemp, fi.Name);
                File.Copy(rutaImg, tmpFile);
                fi = null;
            }

            using (Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(tmpFile)))
            {
                int originalWidth = orig.Width;
                int originalHeight = orig.Height;
                if (nuevo)
                {
                    escala = (float)(anchoOriginal - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth) / (float)originalWidth;
                }
                int newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * escala);
                int newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * escala);


                Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
                {
                    gr.DrawImage(orig, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
                }
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
                pictureBox1.Image = clone;
                panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum = (int)((panel1.Height- SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarArrowHeight)* escala);
            }
            File.Delete(tmpFile);
        }
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo
>   'XXXXX' porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.

Este error me sale en la ultima linea `File.Delete(tmpFile)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion era bastante sencilla, crear un objeto `Image` y cargar el archivo desde ahi.

Se reemplazo la linea:

```
using (Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(tmpFile)))
```

Por:

```
Image img;
        using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(tmpFile))
        {
            img = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
        }

        using (Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(img))
```

PD: La solucion que planteo @Leandro Tuttini, aunque puede funcionar en otros casos, no es recomendable [trick with stream will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8701748/355264)

Comment: pero es mas o menos lo mismo que propuse, solo que no tuve en cuenta que Bitmap permitia tomar la ruta de la imagen. Edito mi respuesta para que veas la diferencia es solo un tipo de objeto

Comment: Efectivamente asi es, pero descarte la respuesta por la recomendacion de no usar stream de la cual puse el link y finalmente use el metodo que publique, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas el `Image.FromFile()` el archivo queda bloqueado, tiene que usar algo como esto

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(tmpFile)) 
{
  PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream.BaseStream);
}
```

al realizar la lectura como `Stream` dentro de un bloque `using` el archivo no quedara bloqueado y podras eliminarlo

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(tmpFile)) 
using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap(stream))
{
     //codigo

     pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

otra alternativa

```
using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(tmpFile))
using (var orig = new Bitmap(bmpTemp))
{
  //codigo
}
```

solo cambio el primer `StreamReader` por `Bitmap`.

El `delete` de la imagen debes realizarlo fuera de los `using`

Comment: Si bien es cierto lo que dice, fijese que la imagen que cargo al picture box se llama "clone" y es producto de la trasformacion que se hace previamente con el codigo, la imagen 'tmpfile' no deberia quedar liberada al final del bloque 'using' ?

Comment: si bien el Bitmap lo pones dentro del using, estas usando `Image.FromFile(tmpFile)` que lo bloquea

Comment: tienes razon con lo del `Image.FromFile(tmpFile)`, pero usar tu solucion de cargar un stream no me permite la manipulacion  posterior

Comment: el `Bitmap ` permite que le pases un `Stream` en el constructor, digo si es que necesitas este para usar GDI y manipular la imagen antes de mostrarla. Edite la respuesta para mostrar como seria

Comment: Leandro muchas gracias por tu ayuda, estuve revisando un poco mejor y encontre que la solucion que planteas si bien puede llegar a funcionar no es la mas recomendable, publique la respuesta por si a futuro alguien mas tiene la duda, muchas gracias.